# It is possible to test my docker application in a mac OS machine?

Tags: python, macos

I have developed a python based application, and because there are a lot of dependencies I put all in a docker image, so at the end, we can call my application just by typing a simple command line, I have successfully tested my application in my system which is Linux based system. However, I want to test it in a Mac OS based system, but I don't know how to do it, would you help me, please

Thank you in advance

Comment: should be straightforward and the docker image should work the same on macos as on linux

Comment: @RichardBarber you are right. the problem I don't have  a mac machine

Comment: look into a cloud service perhaps like https://virtualmacosx.com or https://www.macincloud.com

Comment: @RichardBarber thank you for your answer. Besides these services are there other free services? I mean a free mac os virtual machine available in the cloud?

Comment: You could definitely try Github Actions: https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/virtual-environments-for-github-hosted-runners

Answer (score -1):

1. Mac OS has preinstalled python `2.7.16`
2. If this version of python is fine go to step 5
3. If you need python 3.x then [install brew](https://brew.sh/)
4. Then use brew to install python 3.x

```sh
brew install python3
```

5. Ensure your python source has proper first line (to avoid conflicts with python 2.7):

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
```

6. Use `pip` to install your app dependencies, first consider use of [Python Virtual Environment](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/venv.html)